# How to clone code from bitbucket through our company domain?

Tags: git, security, bitbucket

We cannot clone from bitbucket to our system when it is connected to mahindra domain, So please help in a detailed answer which can justify the security concerns of our security team and provide a logical, secured and detailed answer.

The error is as follows:

ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org: Temporary failure in name resolution
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

We are able to curl bitbucket.org and we are also able to access portal from mahindra domain. We are only facing issue while using git clone.

Answer (score 0):

> We are able to curl bitbucket.org

So presumably, HTTPS access would work: consider using an HTTPS URL for your Bitbucket repository when cloning.

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/<account>/<repo>
```

(Don't keep the `<>`: it is meant as a placeholder value marker).

Make sure the environment variables `HTTP_PROXY`/`HTTPS_PROXY` are set to `http://your.company.proxy` (`http://`, *not* `https://`)

Comment: the curl command worked when used proxy which is set by the organization. and while I run https git clone, It shows following error. [ fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/<account>/<repo>' : could not resolve host: bitbucket.org]

Comment: @abhishektrivedi First, make sure to replace `<account>` by the actual account name, and don't keep `<>`: it is a placeholder value. Second, check your `HTTP_PROXY`/`HTTPS_PROXY` and `NO_PROXY` environment variable. Make sure the first two are set to `http://your.company.proxy` (http, not https)